# How to select value for certain condition with pandas Series containing dtype list?

Tags: pandas, series

I actually know many ways to do this in Pandas Dataframe and Series with dtype like `float`, But how can I make it work with Series containing dtype `list`?

For example, I want to :

```py
series = pd.Series([[1,2],[2,3,4],[4,6]])
```

`series` is like:

```
0    [1, 2]
1    [2, 3, 4]
2    [4, 6]
dtype: object
```

I want to have rows with it's length longer than 2, which is actually row `1`. I tried:

```
series[len(series) > 2]
```

and

```
series[series.apply(lambda x : len(x) > 1)]
```

Both are not working.

Comment: Check `series[series.map(len) > 2]` and your solution `series[series.apply(lambda x : len(x) > 1)]` should also work just replace `> 1` by `> 2`

Comment: Thanks, I tried the second way again and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

List columns support `.str` accessor methods since they are essentially objects. Try

```
series[series.str.len() > 2]
 
1    [2, 3, 4]
dtype: object
```

If index values of rows that satisfy the condition are needed, we filter on the index instead:

```
series.index[series.str.len() > 2]
# Int64Index([1], dtype='int64')
```

Alternatively, if you want to *remove* rows that are greater than 2 in length, you can use boolean indexing to filter:

```
series[series.str.len() <= 2]

0    [1, 2]
2    [4, 6]
dtype: object
```

Note that your first solution didn't make sense since the condition is scalar, but your apply code would've worked with `len(x) > 2` unless your column also has NaNs, which the `.str` solution handles gracefully.

Comment: If you got some time can you please join [this room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228691/ds5)  :) i would like to discuss a bug in pandas version `1.2.x` ..

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My first solution works when dtype is something like float. It didn't work for list object.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pcgc2.png)
Series are mostly used in **str** because accessor methods. That is the reason str are using in Series

```
series[series.apply(lambda x :len(x) > 2)][enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: Yes, great. And I want to add one thing: directly access rows with condition selected series may cause key error (indexes wasn't reset), I think it would be better:
`series[series.apply(lambda x :len(x) > 2)].iloc[1]`

Comment: Yes of course . Your answer is good and also better form  . Thank you